# Convert view to scrollview for modal controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have some modal controllers that are UIViews and are not scrolling.

Reading on SO, the apple docs and elsewhere, it seems there are three approaches to fixing this:

- Multiselect all the elements within the view and then go
  editor-embedin-UIScrollview.

  change the view to a scrollview in the identity inspector and then
  add the following line to viewdidload:

  [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];

  Copy elements to clipboard, delete the uiview, add a new scrollview
  and copy the elements into the scrollview.  Warning - this destroys
  the positioning of the elements although it does preserve their
  outlet properties.

However, I have tried all of these and the scrollview still does not scroll.

Is there any other step I am missing?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

Getting scrollviews to work is not easy and there is much conflicting advice on the web.

I finally got this to work by setting the content size in a separate method as opposed to viewdidload.

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  self.MainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
  }

Thanks as well to Evo for advice on setting all the vertical dimensions correctly and using freeform in the VC size inspector as it won't work if you don't carefully set these.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have EVER enabled autolayout, even if it's disabled now, you need to:**

1. Select the view controller you plan on scrolling
2. At the bottom right of the storyboard view, click the third button (far right) and then "Reset to Suggested Constraints"
3. Make sure that all the elements in the scrollview are embedded in the desired positions.

**If you are not using autolayout:**

1. Check that the Size of the view controller is set to (320, 2000), or whatever you want.
2. In the Simulated Metrics of the view controller, you can set the size type to Freeform.
3. Then in the tab to the right of Simulated Metrics, you can set the width and height to the desired values.

Please comment any concerns

Comment: I tried middle method above...change uiview to uiscrollview in identity inspector and then add line [(UIScrollView *)self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)];  Then I tried both of your methods, resetting to suggested constraints and also setting the VC as freeform and size below freeform to 320 2000.  However, does not scroll.  The only difference I see is that when I change view to scrollview, it drops all the elements down by 100 points or so.

Comment: Where is the bottom-most element in your scroll view? It might help to place it as far low on the scroll view as possible, or place another element there.

Comment: It's below the visible screen so you can't see it.  I tried moving it way down and no change.  Can't believe it's really this hard to create a scrollview.  I also just tried one from scratch and could not get it to work.

Comment: Ah! You mean the scroll view doesn't fit inside the view? Try setting the size of the view equal to that of the scroll view.

Comment: I don't have a separate view.  The scrollview is by itself inside a VC.  I will try setting both the VC and scrollview the same.

Comment: Do you have the rest of your elements embedded inside your scroll view?

Comment: They were the same...I think.  Even though I changed the class for the view to a scrollview, the tabs say View.  It says width 320 and height 2000 for this View (that I changed to scrollview).  The VC also is set to freeform width 320 height 2000.

Comment: "I changed the class for the view to a scroll view" Would you mind deleting that re-classed view and place a new scroll view in? Make sure to properly reference it. If you have time, try selecting all the elements in the view, Ctrl-X, and paste into the replacement scroll view.

Comment: I just created a new project with one view controller that I set to freeform 320 2000 and one scrollview inside it that I also set to 320 2000.  I then added about 5 labels from top to bottom.  When I build and run, only see top 3 labels... so it is not scrolling.

Comment: Since you will probably have auto layout on, make sure to reset to suggested constraints

Comment: I reset all the contrasts to suggested values and also tried clearing them.  No luck.

Comment: Did you set the scroll delegate?

Comment: No.  Will do that.  What is the principle governing the relationship between the vertical height of the VC and the scroll view i.e. should one be larger than the other?

Comment: Preferably the same. This way you can see all the elements you are moving around with the interface builder. I don't know if there's any advantage to anything, but I keep the content size values the same as the view controller

Comment: To set the scroll delegate, just add "UIScrollViewDelegate" to your header(?) I'm not familiar with objective c, so I recommend searching for this one.

Comment: When you have successfully added the delegate protocol, set the scrollView.delegate = self in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: Finally got it to work with- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.MainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1800);
}  instead of placing this in viewdidload.  Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Great! I forgot about that one... Better late than never